# CodePen refreshing after every run?

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle, codepen

I'm messing around with a simple jQuery script & CodePen keeps refreshing after I click any of the links in my Pen. It's really small - [here it is](https://codepen.io/connorv/pen/boeeey).

Is something in my code causing this? I tried to copy this all over to jsFiddle & it returned an error, I couldn't even run the script.

Here's the script I'm using

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".tabbed ul li a:nth-child(1)").click(function(){

  $(".slider-2").css( "display", "none" );


});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg, it's because I have  tags, so it follows those "links". lol

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` first line in the callback of that 'click' event

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's due to the links.

I added a `return false` to the script and I believe it's triggering how it was intended.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tabbed ul li a:nth-child(1)").click(function(){
      $(".slider-2").css( "display", "none" );
      return false     
    });
});
```

Comment: Ya little stuff like that's easy to miss sometimes